# Codeception sometimes sees a blank page

Tags: codeception

At times Codeception will throw an error because an element is not found, when I look at the screenshot it shows a blank page.

[image]

I do see content in the HTML file that is generated. I guess it just needs more time to load, what would be the most effective way of catching this? (without using visualception).

I was thinking of always waiting for some text in the footer, but may be there's a better approach?

**TLDR;**

**What is most efficient way of checking that page is blank without activating visual detection? (source code is not blank and JS appears to be fully loaded)**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, it was because we run the tests on a different host than the one on which we were coding.

The host usually used when coding: `myapp.local`
The host used only for testing: `myapp-test.local`

The blank page appeared only after clicking on a link. Some links were generated with a full url instead of just the path.

```php
// Codeception goes to myapp-test.local/contact ==> it works
$I->click('Contact me');
<a href="/contact">Contact me</a>

// Codeception goes to myapp.local/contact ==> it doesn't work because this host is not configured to be used with codeception, so there is a blank page
$I->click('Contact me');
<a href="myapp.local/contact">Contact me</a>
```

I don't know if you have a different environment for you tests but maybe it's a similar issue.

Comment: thank you, nope it's the same env. Would be nice if there was a basic way to detecting that the page is blank.